# extending Elasticsearch geohash grid buckets count limit 10000

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to fetch more than 10000th bucket for a geohash grid aggregation, and it seems the max_result_window parameter doesn't affect this limit.

Any ideas how to fetch more than 10k buckets from such an aggregation in elasticsearch?

Comment: have you tried to set [the `size` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-geohashgrid-aggregation.html#_options_3) to  something larger than 10000, which is the default?

Comment: apparently in aggregations, `size`  is only used to sample only the top X number of matching documents

Comment: We're talking about aggregations here, hence the `size` parameter that you put inside the `geohash` aggregation not the `size` parameter at the query level to return documents. This has nothing to do with `max_result_window`